# Removing the previous word when editing text in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-acrobat

What is the keyboard shortcut to remove the previous word when editing text in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro on Microsoft Windows?

The typical keyboard shortcut on Microsoft Windows is  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> but in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro this keyboard shortcut removes the next character.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am quite sure that is the way Adobe works (removes next character). Exactly the same thing happens in Adobe DC which is a much newer version.

What does work reliably is to highlight the subject text and press the Delete key.  This works in both Adobe XI (in my Windows 7 machine) and Adobe DC (in my Windows 10 Host machine).